# How to autopaginate this in Django

Tags: python, html, django, templates, django-models

Hey, dudes i wanna paginate some categories, but when i use autopaginate it always give me a TemplateError. Here is the code that i wanna paginate

```
<!-- red 1 -->
            {% for tpl in cats %}
            <div class="clear Vraz10"></div>
            <div class="clear">
              {% for cat in tpl %}
              <div class="left BoxNapravlenie" onclick="location.href='{{ cat.get_absolute_url }}';">
                  <div class="left"><img src="{% if cat.icon %}{{ cat.icon.url }}{% else %}/media/images/napravlenia/love.gif{% endif %}" style="margin-top: 1px; margin-left: 1px;" title="{{ cat.cms_articles.count }} {% trans "articles" %}" /></div>
                  <div class="left BoxNapravlenieText">{{ cat }}</div>
              </div>
              <div class="left razdelitel2"><img src="/media/images/blank.gif" width="35" height="1" /></div>
              {% endfor %} 
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="clear Vraz10"></div>
            <div class="OtherSection" onClick="location.href='{{ gencat.get_absolute_url }}';">{{ gencat }}</div>
            <div class="clear Vraz10"></div>
```

I wanna paginate the categories, but i can't ;s And i'm asking for your help :}

Comment: What pagination code/plugin/app are you currently using? Django core pagination? The django_pagination app? If you let us know some more details, we'll be able to help more

Comment: I use Django core paginator "from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage, EmptyPage" this code is in views.py

Comment: In news.html it's written something like {% autopaginate results 10%}
{% paginate %}

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible that you use {% autopaginate %} tag inside of block. Move it out of the {% block %} tag if this is the case.

Everything else can be left as is, just the autopaginate tag doesn't work inside of blocks. It doesn't generate any content so it doesn't matter where you put it.

```
{% extends ... %}
{% load pagination_tags %}

{% autopaginate .... %}

... other stuff ...
```